# The efficiency of prime factoring algorithms

Tags: math, primes, prime-factoring

I'm trying to understand what the issue is with creating an efficient prime factorisation algorithm. Specifically, the research I've done so far says that no algorithm has yet been discovered which can find the prime factors of a number in O(n<sup>2</sup>) time. However, the obvious algorithm to me is something like (pseudocode)

```
method(int number, ArrayList<int> listOfPrimes)
{
    int x = 0;
    for (int i : listOfPrimes)
     {
      for (int j : listOfPrimes)
       { 
         if (i * j = number)
          {
            x = i*j;
          }
        }
      }
     return x;
 }
```

I think `method` is O(n<sup>2</sup>), where n is the size of the list. Clearly my understanding of this issue is flawed or there wouldn't be such a fuss about prime factorisation. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: yep thats O(n^2).

Comment: how are you generating listOfPrimes ?

Comment: you might want to ask this on [math.se] as it does not directly relate to programming.

Comment: @DanielA.White my apologies, I thought as my question related primarily to the time complexity of a particular algorithm this would be the right place for it

Comment: Often in number theory the n in O(n) (or whatever) is the number of digits of the numbers, not the numbers themselves. You might want to check the refetrences to see what they mean by O(n).

Comment: @dmuir my understanding is that O(n) here is the number of binary digits - so is this what they mean when they say the algorithms are non-polynomial, that adding one digit to the length of the input doubles the amount of time taken?

Comment: If `n` is 64 (and 64-bit numbers are on the small side in modern cryptography) and `listOfPrimes` is the list of all primes <= 2^64, this list would have (by the prime number theorem) approximately 4.2 x 10^17 entries and would take up over a petabyte of storage. Your algorithm would be `O((10^17)^2)` = `O(10^34)`. Even ignoring the time it would take to create the list and how you would store it, it would take trillions of years to run through your nested loop, even at the rate of a trillion iterations per second. Does that count as a "fuss"?

Comment: @JohnColeman It does indeed. Thanks for helping me gain insight into this fascinating area :)

Comment: Your method() can not factor number=8

Answer (score 3):

As alluded to by @dmuir, your "n" is not the correct "n". Otherwise a trivial O(n) algorithm to factor would be:

```
factor(n){
   for (int i=2; i<n; i++) {
      if (n % i == 0) {
         print("found factor:", i);
         return i;
      }
   }
}
```

For factoring, the size of the input is measured in digits, so "n" is the number of digits or bits in the number. The best algorithms have a very complicated complexity that requires some number theory to understand, but is "greater than" polynomial time yet "less than" exponential time, where the quoted phrases can be made formal. For this reason the complexity is sometimes referred to as "subexponential".

Answer (score 0):

A more optimal way would be

```
method(int number, ArrayList<int> listOfPrimes)
{
    int x = 0;
    for (int i : listOfPrimes)
    {
        while(number%i == 0){
            number /= i;
            x++;
        }

    }
    return x;
 }
```

this returns the count prime factors of a number. the complexity would be

> O(n + number_of_prime_factors)

where n is the length of listOfPrimes

Comment: So, have I misunderstood what polynomial time is? Or is there some other factor that makes prime factorisation hard?

Comment: This is supposing that listOfPrimes is generated, generating that would be the main headache

Comment: Also the complexity would be much less since the inner while loop would run only the number of prime factors times

Comment: So, just so that I'm clear: the difficult part is generating a list of primes? I thought you could check whether a number is prime in polynomial time, so wouldn't generating this list be trivial?

Comment: depends on how large the number is but yes that can be done in polynomial time